# Ubicación de postgresql.conf en Linux

Tags: postgresql, server

en la carpeta /etc no encuentro el fichero postgresql para poder acceder a postgresql.conf y asi poder configurar las ip que accepte.

Tengo opensuse leap 15 y la version de postgresql es postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.5.

Esto es debido a que cuando quiero crear un servidor con pgAdmin, obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> falló la conexión al servidor en «localhost» (::1), puerto 5432:
> FATAL: la autentificación Ident falló para el usuario «postgres»

Comment: Buscaste en esta dirección? /var/lib/pgsql/data/

Comment: O como usuario postgres ejecuta esto: psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'